# OrientDB: merge what to what?

Tags: merge, orientdb

I am a bit puzzled by OrientDB's API documentation.
The ODocument#[merge()](https://orientdb.com/javadoc/2.2.x/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/record/impl/ODocument.html#merge-com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument-boolean-boolean-) method says:

> Merge current document with the document passed as parameter. If the field already exists then the conflicts are managed based on the value of the parameter 'iUpdateOnlyMode'.
>
> Parameters:
> **iOther** - Other ODocument instance to merge
> **iUpdateOnlyMode** - if true, the other document properties will always be added or   overwritten. If false, the missed properties in the "other" document will be removed by original document
> **iMergeSingleItemsOfMultiValueFields** - If true, merges single items of multi field fields (collections, maps, arrays, etc)

From this, I have no idea what merges into what when. And this is the improved state, it [used to be worse](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/orient-database/BpHMZkL6PAg/V9S1FCX9TXsJ) as there were two methods with even more unclear description.

Does anyone have a normal explanation of what gets merged into what? Perhaps Ron Kittle could know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests and it seems the API is a bit weirdly named or misdocumented.

I would expect `doc1.merge(doc2)` to merge `doc2` into `doc1`. Because you're typically editing doc1 and can merge multiple things in succession, like this:

```
doc1.merge(partialDocA);
doc1.merge(partialDocB);
doc1.merge(partialDocC);
```

From the documentation of `merge()`, it sounds like OrientDB has it like this:

```
partialDocA.merge(doc1, true, false);
partialDocB.merge(doc1, true, false);
partialDocC.merge(doc1, true, false);
```

Where the `true` makes `merge` not delete the rest of `doc1`. With `false` it would end up being just `partialDocC`. Well, what kind of merge is that? That's called replace, not merge.

But after I ran some tests, it seems that the first case is true.

If it's true, it should be named `mergeFrom(targetDoc, replaceInsteadOfMerge, somethingWithMultiFields)`.

---

So unless I overlooked something, saving a document from a `Map` looks like this:

```
public ODocument mergeDocument(Map<String, Object> incomingDocMap)
{
    String sourceUri = (String) incomingDocMap.get(DocumentAttributes.SOURCE_URI.toString());
    if (null == sourceUri)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Document sourceUri is null.");
    String docType = (String) incomingDocMap.get(Crawler.Attributes.TYPE);
    if (null == docType)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Document docType is null.");

    // Get a document by sourceUri
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + docType + " WHERE sourceuri=?";
    activateOnCurrentThread();
    List<ODocument> results = db.command(new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>(sql)).execute(sourceUri);
    if (results.size() == 0)
        throw new RuntimeException("No document with sourceUri '"+sourceUri+"'.");

    // Update it from the given map.
    ODocument incomingDoc = new ODocument(docType);
    incomingDoc.fromMap(incomingDocMap);
    //ODocument merged = incomingDoc.merge(results.get(0), true, false);
    ODocument merged = results.get(0).merge(incomingDoc, true, false);
    //merged.save(); /// Duplicated key
    return merged;
}
```

The method even doesn't have the `@return` filled so I have no idea whether I can continue using the original `ODocument`.

Well done, OrientDB.